# nginx | How to redirect json from auth_request to user

Tags: nginx

I have a problem, I need to make it so that when an error occurs during auth_request, for example, 401, the json sent by the service is taken and sent to the user. The json sent by the service contains information that can change, but auth_request returns a standard html error - 401

Or make it possible to send two requests instead of auth_request, the first request acting as an auth_request, and the next one as a proxy